# Getting a unique number at upload

Tags: javascript, php, random, numbers

I have an upload script, it runs when the user clicks on submit, and it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
    // Initialiseer uploadifive
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
        'auto'              : false,
        'checkScript'       : '/uploadifive/Sample/check-exists.php',
        'onFallback'        : function () {
                                  window.location = '/home.php';
                              },
        'method'            : 'post',
        'queueID'           : 'queue',
        'uploadScript'      : '/upload/uploadifive.php',
        'removeCompleted' : true,
        'onUploadComplete'  : function (file, data) {
                                  console.log(data);
                              }
    });

    // Hang een click-event aan de knop
    $('#subby').on('click', function () {
        // Werk formData van uploadifive bij met de betreffende waarden
        $('#file_upload').data('uploadifive').settings.formData = {
            'timestamp'   : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
            'token'       : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
            'projectnr'   : $('input[name=projectnr]').val(),
            'gebruiker'   : $('input[name=gebruiker]').val(),
            'gebruikerid' : $('input[name=userId]').val(),
            'mapId'       : $( "#mapId option:selected" ).val(), // moet dit niet val() zijn???
            'uploadbash'  : '<?php echo $uploadbash; ?>',
            'upload_reden' : $( "#upload_reden option:selected" ).val(),
            'todo'        : $("input[name=todo]:checked").val(),
            'lid'         : $('input[name="lid[]"]:checked').serialize()
        };
        // Voer de upload uit
        $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Now I'd like to modify the above and build the following thing:

When the script runs, it has to run the page `randomnumber.php` in the background, and send the number it receives back as 'uploadbash'  : ''

Is this possible and how should I do this?

---

It won't work, i do this now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
    // Initialiseer uploadifive
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive({

        'auto'              : false,
        'onFallback'        : function () {
                                  window.location = '/home.php';
                              },
        'method'            : 'post',
        'queueID'           : 'queue',
        'uploadScript'      : '/upload/uploadifive.php',
        'removeCompleted' : true,
        'onUploadComplete'  : function (file, data) {
                                  console.log(data);
                              }
    });

    // Hang een click-event aan de knop
    $('#subby').on('click', function () {

        // Werk formData van uploadifive bij met de betreffende waarden
        $('#file_upload').data('uploadifive').settings.formData = {

              'checkScript'       : 

$.ajax({
      url: '/upload/number.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {search: "beeeeeeeh"}
    }).done(function () {
                alert("test");
                $("#result").html(data);   

                 }),            
            'timestamp'   : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
            'token'       : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
            'projectnr'   : $('input[name=projectnr]').val(),
            'gebruiker'   : $('input[name=gebruiker]').val(),
            'gebruikerid' : $('input[name=userId]').val(),
            'mapId'       : $( "#mapId option:selected" ).val(), // moet dit niet val() zijn???
            'uploadbash'  : '<?php echo $uploadbash; ?>',
        'upload_reden' : $( "#upload_reden option:selected" ).val(),
        'todo'        : $("input[name=todo]:checked").val(),
            'lid'         : $('input[name="lid[]"]:checked').serialize(),
        'number'      : $("#result").html(data)
        };
        // Voer de upload uit
        $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

So i've added:

```
'checkScript'       : 

    $.ajax({
          url: '/upload/number.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {generateNumber: "yes"}
        }).done(function () {
            alert("test");
                    $("#result").html(data);   

                     }),
```

And:

```
'number'      : $("#result").html(data)
```

But when i click "upload" i get this in firebug:

> ReferenceError: data is not defined
>   $("#result").html(data);    }),

The alert "test" does popup.

Comment: First do a $.get to randomnumber.php to get your value, and do all of the above stuff on its success() callback

Comment: Tried something, but it doen't work, see the post below.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that this

```
    {'checkScript'       : 

    $.ajax({
      url: '/upload/number.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {search: "beeeeeeeh"}
    }).done(function () {})
```

does not assign what you are expecting to checkScript. it is an asynchronous call, so you have to wait for it to return (in done() or success()) before you can use the data it will provide.

```
 // Hang een click-event aan de knop
    $('#subby').on('click', function () {
        // Werk formData van uploadifive bij met de betreffende waarden
        //when we click, do a call to the backend...
        $.ajax({
           url: '/upload/number.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {generateNumber: "yes"}
        }).success(function(numberPHPResult){ //***
        //and when it comes back, populate the form
           $('#file_upload').data('uploadifive').settings.formData = {
            'checkScript': numberPHPResult, //***
            'timestamp'   : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
            'token'       : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>',
            'projectnr'   : $('input[name=projectnr]').val(),
            'gebruiker'   : $('input[name=gebruiker]').val(),
            'gebruikerid' : $('input[name=userId]').val(),
            'mapId'       : $( "#mapId option:selected" ).val(), // moet dit niet val() zijn???
            'uploadbash'  : '<?php echo $uploadbash; ?>',
            'upload_reden' : $( "#upload_reden option:selected" ).val(),
            'todo'        : $("input[name=todo]:checked").val(),
            'lid'         : $('input[name="lid[]"]:checked').serialize()
           };
           // Voer de upload uit
           $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');
       })

    });
```

Also, instead of posting an answer, you should edit your question if you want to provide more information.

Finally, if you want to learn Javascript in more depth, Douglas Crockford is your man.

http://javascript.crockford.com/ online stuff
http://www.amazon.co.uk/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742 //book
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7664379246A246CB //video

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass the object returned as a parameter of the `done()` method chained. So `done(data)` Try with:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/upload/number.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {generateNumber: "yes"}
}).done(function(data) 
{
    console.log(data);
    alert("test");
    $("#result").html(data.responseText); //If I'm not wrong data is a XMLHttpRequest object    
});
```

Or even better:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/upload/number.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {generateNumber: "yes"},
    success: function(data) 
    {
        console.log(data);
        alert("test");
        $("#result").html(data.responseText); //If I'm not wrong data is a XMLHttpRequest object    
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
    {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    });
```